# With Laravel, how can I organize cities in my migration tables so that I can assign them unique slugs for filtering business listings?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

***tl;dr: How can I organize my database tables so that I can turn the state and city name into a unique slug, exactly like the website justia.com/lawyers does?***

A client has me working on a directory listing website for lawyers where they would like users to be able to find attorneys by their practice area (category) and the city and state or zip code. In order to make SEO friendly URLs I planned to mimick a very similar website which has the following URL structure (a coup

```
https://www.justia.com/lawyers/criminal-law/california/los-angeles
https://www.justia.com/lawyers/personal-injury/texas/dallas
https://www.justia.com/lawyers/personal-injury/washington/spokane
```

In order to achieve this I've created the following tables and planned to use the sluggable laravel package to automatically generate the slugs when saving the elloquent models:

```
Schema::create('lawyers', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('first_name', 50);
      $table->string('middle_name', 50)->nullable();
      $table->string('last_name', 50);
      $table->string('email', 256)->unique();
      $table->string('phone', 15);
      $table->string('website',200);
      $table->string('company',100);
      $table->date('licensed_since');
      $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 16);
    $table->integer('zip');
    $table->string('state', 2);
    $table->decimal('lat', '8', '6');
    $table->decimal('long', 10, 6);
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});


 Schema::create('practice_areas', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('practice_area', 200);
      $table->string('slug')->unique();
});

/*------------------------ Pivot Tables ------------------------*/

Schema::create('city_lawyer', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->integer('lawyer_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('lawyer_id')->references('id')->on('lawyers');
      $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
});

Schema::create('lawyer_practice_area', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->integer('lawyer_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('lawyer_id')->references('id')->on('lawyers');
      $table->integer('practice_area_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('practice_area_id')->references('id')->on('practice_areas');
});

/*------- Not a part of the issue but here for reference  -------*/

Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('address1', 100);
      $table->string('address2', 50);
      $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('address_lawyer', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->integer('lawyer_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('lawyer_id')->references('id')->on('lawyers');
      $table->integer('address_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses');
});
```

As of right now, the practice_area section of the website is working fine. I run into issues when I attempt to do this with the cities though because certain city names are listed in the city table multiple times - since some cities have multiple zip codes and different states often share city names.

***So my question is, what's the best way to organize the database so that I can use the city and states as a slug like the website justia.com/lawyers does?***

Comment: A thought I had was making the slug in the city table be "state/city" instead of just the slug of the city and moving the zip code to a new table so its a one to many relationship. Would I be able to have a laravel route where the variable has a slash in it though? (Instead of it being a separator)

Comment: Yes, no, kinda. You cannot use a `/` in a url for something else than a separator, though you could either pass 2 arguments or have the second argument be an optional one and check and parse accordingly.